# How to cleanup/fix my mapping of cell-array MATLAB code so I do not hit a recursive limit?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell-array

I have to solve a problem where I have to take a vector for ex [1 2 3] and map it using a table such that 1 = [1 1], 2 = [4 6 8], 3 = [6 9 12 15] (a shorter example of actual problem)
So my function ideally would be: 
   `convert([1 2 3]) = [1 1 4 6 8 6 9 12 15]`

My thinking process is that I have to make the vector a cell array first so that I can replace the values to others that different dimensions, and then convert cell array back to vector/matrix.
This is what I have so far

```
y = num2cell(x);

for n = 1:length(x)
    if y{n} == 0
        y{n} = [0 2];
    elseif y{n} == 1
        y{n}= [1 1];
    elseif y{n} == 2
        y{n} = [4 6 8];
    elseif y{n} == 3
        y{n} = [6 9 12 15];

    elseif y{n} < 0
        y{n} = 1 - convert(-(x+1));
    end
    output = cell2mat(y);
end
end
```

Everything works fine if my input has the positive values of 0, 1 , 2, or 3 in the initial vector. However, I need to have this condition where if the vector has a negative entry (x), the negative entry gets entered such that `y{n} = 1 - convert(-(x+1))` However, when I do this, I get an error of hitting recursive limit.
Is there a way to fix my code such that it will work with negative values and not produce an error? Also, is there a way to do it without using a for or while loop? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't needs cells at all but to answer your question I suggest you deal with negatives before you loop to avoid any recursion which is also unnecessary So something along the lines of this assuming I've followed your code correctly:

```
negs = x < 0;
x(negs) = -(x(negs) + 1)

y = num2cell(x);

for n = 1:length(x)
    if y{n} == 0
        y{n} = [0 2];
    elseif y{n} == 1
        y{n}= [1 1];
    elseif y{n} == 2
        y{n} = [4 6 8];
    elseif y{n} == 3
        y{n} = [6 9 12 15];
    end

    if negs(n)
        y{n} = 1 - x;
    end
    output = cell2mat(y);
    end
end
```

BTW I have a feeling that this line `y{n} = 1 - x;` should actually be `y{n} = 1 - x(n);`  (i.e. your original code should have read `y{n} = 1 - convert(-(x(n)+1));`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried your suggestion just now, and I get this error: "In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the
same." and to clarify, the output for a vector of say, [1 2 3 -1] would be 'convert([1 2 3 -1]) = [1 1 4 6 8 6 9 12 15 1 -1]' since with the entry of -1, it will be 1 - convert(-(-1+1)) = 1 - convert(0) = 1 - [0 2] = [1 -1]

Comment: It works that it there is no longer an error (thanks for that!), however it reads a different sequence of numbers, so I guess that means that its not computing (1 - convert(-(x+1)))

Comment: It's actually just mapping as if it was convert(0), it is not subtracting that sequence from 1.

Comment: Sorry my bad again, the last `elseif` should now just be an `if`. I think you should try and rewrite this without using cells though. Rather just concatenate the matrices i.e.: `yn = [4 6 8]; output = [output, yn];`